# NetBeans won't show static web files under "Projects" view

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a multi-module maven project in which one module is called "webapp" and has all the static files and directories for these static files in src/main/webapp.

I am used to seeing these files+directories under the "Projects" view, but now they no longer appear. (I switched to the latest version of NetBeans, which might be part of the reason.) What I see now is

```
webapp Maven Webapp (war)
   -> Other Sources
        -> src/main/resources
   -> Dependencies
   -> Project Files
```

What's missing here is src/main/webapp, which is the directory for all my static files and web content. Of course, I can see it under the "Files" view, but I don't want to use the "Files" view. Why is it that I can't see this directory under the "Projects" view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the answer from a coworker. I had to install a few NetBeans plugins... I think it was Java EE Base that did it.